# what steps I should follow to identify the difference in the time

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel, where a start and end time is given of a particular user and I have to take out the difference using python, The doubt I have is the start and the end time is given one below the another.

I am confused how do I separate the start and end time of user and then calculate the difference.

snap of the data

[image]

what steps should I take or the logic I should use?

Comment: Too broad of a question. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions, not for detailed step-by-step guidelines for writing whole programs. You need a tutorial, which is beyond the scope of the site. If you have already written some code but it isn't working as expected, please provide the relevant code and ask a focused question about it. Otherwise, you haven't done the preliminary work needed to ask a good question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

This video should help along with the functionality of your code [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0DNcTnreuY)

For logic, you could use a for loop to parse through each line using `for i in range(sheet.nrows)` or something near that and every time it runs the loop add a number to the counter, if the numbers odd save the value to a start time list or dictand if the values even save the value to an end time list or dict